# Deploy the application. NET for Windows Mobile 6.x

Tags: compact-framework, sql-server-ce, installation, cab, windows-mobile-6

created in a prjeto. NET Compact Framework 3.5 for Windows Mobile 6.x.

I wonder how you do to create the installer (. cab) for this project?
How do deploy. NET Framework and SQL CE for Mobile?

Given a novice user.

Today I have an installer.cab and .msi for Windows
But to my system running is to install the SQL CE and Compact Framework 3.5. How to download and install these applications after the installation of my system?

Would not want to send these applications together because the size of the installer can get big

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to do a multi-CAB install.  [MSDN covers it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx).  [CodeProject here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/InstallMultipleCABFiles.aspx).